# Convert Pandas dataframe to time series

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
Out[57]: 
      lastrun           rate
0   2013-11-04 12:15:02   0
1   2013-11-04 13:14:50   4
2   2013-11-04 14:14:48   10
3   2013-11-04 16:14:59   16
```

I would like to convert that into an hourly time series and interpolate missing values (15:00) so that I end up with:

```
2013-11-04 12:00:00   0
2013-11-04 13:00:00   4
2013-11-04 14:00:00   10
2013-11-04 15:00:00   13
2013-11-04 16:00:00   16
```

How do I convert / map the dataframe data to a time series in Pandas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your 'lastrun' has datetime objects:

```
In [22]: s = df.set_index('lastrun').resample('H')['rate']
In [23]: s
Out[23]: 
lastrun
2013-11-04 12:00:00     0
2013-11-04 13:00:00     4
2013-11-04 14:00:00    10
2013-11-04 15:00:00   NaN
2013-11-04 16:00:00    16
Freq: H, dtype: float64

In [24]: s.interpolate()
Out[24]: 
lastrun
2013-11-04 12:00:00     0
2013-11-04 13:00:00     4
2013-11-04 14:00:00    10
2013-11-04 15:00:00    13
2013-11-04 16:00:00    16
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

That's if you want linear interpolation. There's a [bunch more options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#interpolation) in the upcoming .13 release!

Comment: That is all kinds of awesome.  I can't wait for .13!

Comment: Thanks but getting this 'interpolate() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)'. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you're `s` is a DataFrame. Try `s = df.set_index('lastrun').resample('H')['rate']` (Note the `rate` at the end. The API changed a bit so in .13 this will work on a Series or DataFrame)

Comment: Coming back to this, what if the missing data was at the end of the dataframe? So perhaps in the above `2013-11-04 17:00:00` was missing? So etiher data before or afterwards.