# Pandas Reordering Dataframe to Time Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with unlabeled columns with the following structure

```
0    101   100001   DT23    NaT   1900-01-01 20:00:00    DT24    1900-01-01 20:02:00 
1    101   100002   DT24    1900-01-01 20:02:00    1900-01-01 20:04:00     DT23   1900-01-01 20:05:05 
2    102   200001   DT23    NaT   1900-01-01 20:05:00    DT24    1900-01-01 20:07:00 
3    102   200002   DT24    1900-01-01 20:07:00    1900-01-01 20:09:00     DT23   1900-01-01 20:10:05
```

I would like to shape the data to be different time series for each unique first column value. For "101" the data would be:

```
1900-01-01 20:00:00 DT23
1900-01-01 20:02:00 DT24
1900-01-01 20:04:00 DT24
1900-01-01 20:05:05 DT23
```

I have tried to iterate through the column for each unique value and append to a new series, but since the column names are not the same, I end up with a dataframe rather than a time series. How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide your current code sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully ending with a DataFrame, then this answer can show you how to convert a DF to a time series

[Convert Pandas dataframe to time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914944/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-time-series)

Hope this helps.